# Can git's `assume-unchanged` be shared?

Tags: git

In a Git repo, we have a config file with some sensible defaults. It's checked in because everyone needs to have **something** in that file.

However, we may each wish to tweak it as we're working. Generally, these changes should not be checked in.

I can solve this for myself with `git update-index --assume-unchanged the_file`. After that, any changes I make to it do not show up with `git status`.

However, just like I can list a file in `.gitignore` and commit `.gitignore` to say "this file should be ignored on any machine", I'd like to "check in" my `--assume-unchange`, to say "**changes to** this file should be ignored on any machine".

Is this possible?

Comment: No, `update-index --assume-unchanged` is a local setting. Many users suggest checking in a template / sample config file like `config.sample.txt` and instructing users to copy this to `config.txt` and modify as appropriate. `config.txt` is ignored via `.gitignore`, but `config.sample.txt` is tracked. There are many questions here about this.

Comment: Maybe you can create a script which discards changes and a  `gitattributes` file to apply these filter on the desired files.

Comment: @Chris - yep, I have used an example file before and forgot about that. Probably the best approach. :)